# Chrome 63 '[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**How can I disable this error message in Chrome?**

[image]

---

I do know `id`'s are supposed to be unique. But in this case there is a difference between a desktop view and mobile view. These `id`'s are not interfering each other.

I got two search `form`'s with the same `id` *search*. One is rendered as a desktop view, while the other is in another component designed for the mobile environment. I cannot simply change the `id`'s, so that they are unique.

The site is responsive using *bootstrap*. The desktop element uses the classes `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm`. While the mobile variant is using, `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg`.

I got this error since a few days, before ive not seen this error shown up in the console while developing. While the layout isn't changed in the meanwhile.

> I tried to reproduce the problem inside a fiddle. But funny thing is, no error is shown. Even when I create 10 elements with the same `id`. I wonder why it doens't log any error there. https://jsfiddle.net/obco1dju/

Comment: You probably have a password inout in this page, and a link explaining why you get this this error in the error message itself.

Comment: Also if both elements are in the same Document at the same time, they do interfere, whatever CSS rules you apply on them.

Comment: Yes, but not visibly. Because the other is for the mobile view.

Comment: DOM methods and other underlying codes relying on the id attributes (e.g browser autofill maybe?) do not care about the visibility of your elements. ids should be unique period. Now, this is just a warning message chrome introduced, and if everything worked before they did set this message, it should still work now.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Chrome is driving me mad and i can't be arsed fixing the duplicate ids right now.